# How can I ntegrate a .txt file into this code with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, roman-numerals

```
class py_solution:

def roman_to_int(self, s):
    rom_val = {'I': 1, 'V': 5, 'X': 10, 'L': 50, 'C': 100, 'D': 500, 'M': 1000}
    int_val = 0
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if i > 0 and rom_val[s[i]] > rom_val[s[i - 1]]:
            int_val += rom_val[s[i]] - 2 * rom_val[s[i - 1]]
        else:
            int_val += rom_val[s[i]]
    return int_val

num = (py_solution().roman_to_int())

from collections import OrderedDict

def write_roman(num):

   roman = OrderedDict()
   roman[1000] = "M"
   roman[900] = "CM"
   roman[500] = "D"
   roman[400] = "CD"
   roman[100] = "C"
   roman[90] = "XC"
   roman[50] = "L"
   roman[40] = "XL"
   roman[10] = "X"
   roman[9] = "IX"
   roman[5] = "V"
   roman[4] = "IV"
   roman[1] = "I"

def roman_num(num):
    for r in roman.keys():
        x, y = divmod(num, r)
        yield roman[r] * x
        num -= (r * x)
        if num > 0:
            roman_num(num)
        else:
            break

return "".join([a for a in roman_num(num)])

print (write_roman(num))
```

num = (py_solution().roman_to_int('here')) if you insert any roman number in the 'here' part it will return the most efficient output of that roman number. like if you input 'IIIIIIIIIII' it will return XI. I have to input a text file in the 'here' part containing a 1000 roman numbers. how do i do this.

Comment: What do you mean by integrate ?

Comment: well, I can put in all the roman numbers with hand into(here): num = (py_solution().roman_to_int('here'))

Comment: but thats to much, I want to run the script on the file i have

Comment: Hello, your code is full of errors so even with @BlueSheepToken's solution I doubt it works. `roman_to_int()` can be a function and does not need a `self` argument. Everything could be a function actually so the class `py_solution` is not needed. What does this line try to do? `num = (py_solution().roman_to_int())` because without argument it won't do anything. Are you using an IDE or just coding in Notepad?

Comment: coding in notepad

Comment: An IDE would help a ton with finding syntax issues :)

Comment: num = (py_solution().roman_to_int('here')) if you insert any roman number it will return the most efficient output of that roman number. like if you input 'IIIIIIIIIII' it will return XI

Comment: i need to input a list of a 1000 roman numbers into the 'here' part. that is the issue im having. i still dont know how

Answer (score 1):

You can use your file as an input to the program, when launching your script you need to :

```
python your_script.py < your_file.txt
```

And get the inputs in your python script with

```
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    print(line)
```

or just open your file in python with

```
with open(your_file_path.txt, 'r') as file: #open it in read mode
    roman_numbers = file.readlines()
#Close the file when exiting the with statement
```

Comment: can't seem to make this work: import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    print(line)

Comment: How do you launch your python script?

Comment: You miss the < symbol to specify the input